# Get data from a join table in inner join

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following four tables:

Subscription:

```
book_id, duration, subscriber
```

Book:

```
book_id, book_name
```

Genre:

```
genre_id, genre_name
```

book_to_genre:

```
genre_id, book_id
```

For a certain user (subscriber) I would like to get all rows from subscription. The book name should be fetched from table Book. I know this is done with an inner join:

```
SELECT Book.book_name, Subscription.duration from Subscription INNER JOIN Book on Subscription.book_id = Book.book_id where Subscription.subscriber = "somevalue";
```

What if I would like to fetch genre_name from table Genre, where Genre.genre_id = book_to_genre.genre_id for that book?

Comment: I don't see any field called `user`.  What do you mean by this?  And your second requirement sounds like a different query altogether.

Comment: Better add all the things needed `(table structure + sample input + expected output)`

Comment: @timbiegeleisen : My bad, I eas not being very clear. Users are called subscribers when we refer to the table subscription. As for my second requirement, it is not a different query. For each user I get the name of the book he borrowed. This book has a genre (table book_to_genre). This genre has a name (table genre). I want that genre name for each book that was borrowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your initial query that will return `genre_name`:
- I added the field `genre_name` in the `SELECT` part
- I added table aliases to make it easier to read
- I added 2 `INNER JOIN`: one between tables `book` and `book_to_genre`, the other between tables `book_to_genre` and `Genre`

```
SELECT b.book_name, s.duration, g.genre_name
FROM Subscription s
INNER JOIN Book b on s.book_id = b.book_id
INNER JOIN book_to_genre bg ON b.book_id = bg.book_id
INNER JOIN Genre g ON bg.genre_id = g.genre_id
where s.subscriber = "somevalue";
```

Documentation:
- [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)
- [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)